# MySQL central database with unique ids

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a question about the id generation with a central database and several decentralized databases. I red something about replications but finally, I haven't founds something that solved my question.

I developed a web applications for different clients. Each of the application has its own mysql database. Therefore one database knows nothing about the other. 
As a next step, I want to merge all data into a centralized database for an internal backend system. However, the decentralized databases should still have only their own data. I once worked with MSSQL-Server and they had the Merge-/ Transaction-replication. Unfortunately, I never did something with MySQL. Therefore, I have two questions:

1.) Is it possible with MySQL to create a form of Replication, that has all data on the Master (central) Server, and only the data on the slave server, that was inserted in this application?

2.) Is it somehow possible, to create a unique ID at a slave, that is unique for all databases? E.g. an invoice is created at one of the databases. This invoice ID must be unique and is not allowed to be created in another database.

Would be great if someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

1) yes. you can replicate individual databases.  See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-solutions-partitioning.html).
2) there are several ways to do this:

- primary key of slave-id + auto increment key
- guid/uuid
- unique key at master which is copied to slave

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that replication of individual databases works, but how is it possible to store e.g. the data from DB1, DB2 and DB3 together in one target database (I want to have all the individual data in one central database, but also keep the individual data at their databases). Second, unfortunately, the Id must be autoincrement with a maximal length of 15. That means, DB1 creates an Invoide # 10001, DB2 #10002, then DB1 #10003, DB4 #10004 and so on.

Comment: You could sync the various bits with an insert trigger.